# What is the easiest way to show an image with text:hover?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to show an `image`(company logo 150 x 100 px) on `text:hover` when the user is coming on the **company name**. The image should show on the right side of the name.

I don't know if I can solve it with CSS3 or if I need some jQuery for it - which I wouldn't prefer much.

Any ideas?

My HTML

```
<div class="supplier_box_top">
    <p class="name">Company Name</p>
    <p class="city">Country</p>
    <p class="info" ><a href="#" target="_blank" id="1" class="show_info_box">nfoBox</a></p>
    <p class="site_link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">www.your-company.com</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<img>` is placed after the *Company Name* `.name`, Then you could use adjacent `a + b` or general `a ~ b` sibling selectors to display the image:

```css
img.logo {
   display: none;
}

.name:hover ~ img.logo {
    display: inline;
}
```

However, you could put the image inside the same paragraph and use the following:

```
<p class="name">Company Name <img src="" /></p>
```

```css
.name {
   position: relative;
}

.name img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
   display: none;
}

.name:hover img {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved with CSS3:

```css
.name:hover::before {
    content: url(your_image_url.jpg);
    float: right;
}
```

*Note: the path to the image is relative to the CSS file*

Thats the most basic solution. The image will be floating the company name from the right side. Do you want more sophisticated styling?

*However* if you want to support also IE7 and older you should add the image traditional way and style the `hover` the same as in the example above, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="supplier_box_top">
    <p class="name">
        <img class="company_image" src="my_image.jpg">
        Company Name
    </p>
    <p class="city">Country</p>
    <p class="info" ><a href="#" target="_blank" id="1" class="show_info_box">nfoBox</a></p>
    <p class="site_link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">www.your-company.com</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.name .company_name {
    display: none;
}
.name:hover .company_name {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but when I copy/past your code it doesn't work. I guess I might do some mistake which I couldn't figure out yet. The image is not showing on hover but right from the beginning on the left side! Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I updated the answer. Take a look. Anyway, the first solution should work from the beginning (the one with `::before`)